# How to get the product ID in Magento 2 plugin

Tags: magento2, product, module

Hi all I am using Magento 2 and I want to get the product Id on all pages.
Now i amable to get the product id in product details pae (Product single page). but i am not getting those in product listing pages. it says calling undefined object like error message.

```
 <?php

namespace Vendor\module\Plugin;

class Product
{       
public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

    $product- = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
    // here this $product is seems like undefined only in product listing pages.

    return $result + 100;
}
}
```

Please see comment in my code,  how can I get the product id here?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic is not right. You are using a plugin, so do not need to use registry `current_product`.

**$subject** can provide the **product id** using `$subject->getId()`

Comment: Yes that is perfect!

Comment: One more question, i got the ID, but the same way i am not getting the weight and price of the product like this. `$subject->getWeight();` but it is coming in detail page of that product